# Converting a static HTML template into a WP theme - How do I specify page content?

Tags: theme-development, html

I've been creating and selling static HTML templates for too long now, so I decided to convert one of my single page templates into a WP theme to sell on one of the marketplaces, however I faced a big misunderstanding of what the standard theme package should come with.

I've looked through dozens of tutorials and built a simple single page theme that has a navigation panel and a footer. The next step was to fill the page with content. That's where all the tuts suggested to insert your page body *html code* into the text area of Pages -> New page. However, I though that if I sell a WP theme, I don't expect a user to copy paste any HTML, I thought it's only that he/she has to fill some fields to make it working. Am I mistaken, do users have to handle HTML code and insert it into the text area of a new page when they purchase a new template? Any help or explanation how it usually works would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Learn more about WordPress loop , `WP_Query`, `the_content()` , `the_excerpt()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is how it works:

1. Create HTML template.
2. Add sample content to your template(from page backend) while converting HTML to WP theme.
3. Ater finalising your WP theme, export all the WordPress backend content (sample data from WP backend) into the XML file and provide that XML files to your client if they want to get the same look and feel as you have shown it into your sample site.
4. Write a documentation on how to change content/style/look of a part of your WP theme.
5. Handle the cases explicitly where there is no data coming from WP backend (i.e. user hasn't imported your XML file into their site).

Note: Get a template from some site and try installing it. Raed their documentation, you will get a fair idea of the process.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've downloaded one of the free templates out there, they customize it's content with a build in Customizer or something like this. I think it's way more difficult than I expected.